# Как можно вывести все категории со всеми записями в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо получить список всех категорий из кастомного типа записей, каждая из которых будет содержать список принадлежащих ей записей. Вроде этого:

```
Категория А
Запись кат А 1
Запись кат А 2
Запись кат А N
...
Категория B 
...
```

и так далее.

В шаблоне пытаюсь совместить функции `get_categories()` и `get_posts()`:

```
$args = array(
  'type'                     => 'glossary',
  'child_of'                 => 0,
  'parent'                   => '',
  'orderby'                  => 'name',
  'order'                    => 'ASC',
  'hide_empty'               => 0,
  'hierarchical'             => 1,
  'exclude'                  => '',
  'include'                  => '',
  'number'                   => 0,
  'taxonomy'                 => 'gl_section',
  'pad_counts'               => false
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
if( $categories ){
  foreach( $categories as $cat ){
    // Данные в объекте $cat
    $id = $cat->term_id;
    $title = $cat->name;
     echo $id;
     echo $title; 
     $args = array('category' => $id, 'post_type' => 'glossary' , 'category_name' => $title);
    print_r( get_posts($args) );
  }
}
```

Результат:

```
        70 D Array ( ) 
        69 F Array ( ) 
        71 G Array ( )
```

То есть ID категории и название выводятся, а посты нет. Пробовал искать функцию, выводящую все сразу - не обнаружил. Какие еще могут быть способы? Или в WP в принципе невозможно совместить записи и таксономию?

Также вскрылась другая проблема: если даже я назначаю в массиве `$args`
параметру `'category' => конкретное числовое значение`, эффект тот же самый, выводится пустой массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день!

Вы сделали всё правильно, но ошибка в том, что переменной $post не присвоено никакое значение, поэтому массив постов пустой.

Сначала надо установить глобальные данные поста (вне цикла) - [setup_postdata()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/setup_postdata).

Не забываем сбросить переопределение глобального значения через [wp_reset_postdata()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_reset_postdata).

Ниже код (реальной рабочий, делал для своего проекта), с поддержкой дочерних категорий. Если есть непонятные моменты - готов уточнить, задавайте вопрос.

```
<?php

    //Запрос категорий
    $args = array(
        'parent'=>'0',
        'pad_counts'=>true,
    );                  
    $categories = get_categories($args);

    //Перебор категорий
    foreach ($categories as $category) 
    {           
        if($category->parent == 0)
        {           
            //Выводим информацию о категории
            $output .= $category->category_nicename;
            $output .= $category->cat_name;
            echo $output;

            //Запрос дочерних категорий (подкатегорий)
            $argsChild = array(
                'child_of'=>$category->term_id,
            );

            $childCategories = get_categories($argsChild);

            //Перебор подкатегорий
            foreach ($childCategories as $childCategory) 
            {
                //Выводим информацию о подкатегории     
                $output .= $childCategory->category_nicename;
                $output .= $childCategory->cat_name;
                echo $output;

                //Получаем список постов подкатегории
                $args = array(
                    'category' => $childCategory->term_id,
                );
                $categoryPosts = get_posts( $args );

                //Выводим посты
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach( $categoryPosts as $post )
                {
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    ?>
                    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                    <?php
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```